# Preprocessor in Blackberry (through bb-ant-tools)

Tags: blackberry, ant, preprocessor

There is a project that has `#preprocess` directives. I.e. there is `#preprocess` directive in the beginning of a file and something like `#ifdef BlackBerrySDK6.0.0` inside the file.

Though it compiles well in eclipse, there are problems using bb-ant-tools. It behaves as though there is no preprocessing: compile errors on strings that should not be included.

I have build.properties file; it is included through `<property file="build.properties">` AND `<jdp file="build.properties">`. I have `BlackBerrySDK5.0.0=true` in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized it myself. I should claim defines="blabla" in properties of  task: `<rapc output="foo" destdir="bar" defines="blabla">`